# Multiple match with different length and calculations in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below,

```
df<- structure(list(TIME = c("02/02/2010", "02/02/2010", "02/02/2010", 
"26/02/2010", "26/02/2010", "26/02/2010", "26/02/2010", "26/02/2010", 
"26/02/2010", "26/02/2010", "26/02/2010", "26/02/2010", "16/03/2010", 
"16/03/2010", "16/03/2010", "16/03/2010", "16/03/2010", "16/03/2010", 
"16/03/2010", "16/03/2010", "16/03/2010", "28/04/2010", "28/04/2010", 
"28/04/2010", "28/04/2010", "28/04/2010", "28/04/2010", "28/04/2010", 
"28/04/2010", "28/04/2010", "05/05/2010", "05/05/2010", "05/05/2010", 
"07/06/2010", "07/06/2010", "07/06/2010", "07/06/2010", "07/06/2010", 
"07/06/2010", "07/06/2010", "07/06/2010", "07/06/2010", "02/07/2010", 
"02/07/2010", "02/07/2010", "02/07/2010", "02/07/2010", "02/07/2010", 
"02/07/2010", "02/07/2010", "02/07/2010", "28/07/2010", "28/07/2010", 
"28/07/2010", "28/07/2010", "28/07/2010", "28/07/2010", "28/07/2010", 
"28/07/2010", "28/07/2010", "10/09/2010", "10/09/2010", "10/09/2010", 
"10/09/2010", "10/09/2010", "10/09/2010", "10/09/2010", "10/09/2010", 
"10/09/2010", "10/10/2010", "10/10/2010", "10/10/2010", "10/10/2010", 
"10/10/2010", "10/10/2010", "10/10/2010", "10/10/2010", "10/10/2010", 
"06/11/2010", "06/11/2010", "06/11/2010", "06/11/2010", "06/11/2010", 
"06/11/2010", "06/11/2010", "06/11/2010", "06/11/2010"), Plot = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), Treat = c("D", "C", "W", "D", "C", "W", 
"C", "W", "D", "D", "W", "C", "D", "C", "W", "C", "W", "D", "D", 
"W", "C", "D", "C", "W", "C", "W", "D", "D", "W", "C", "D", "C", 
"W", "D", "C", "W", "C", "W", "D", "D", "W", "C", "D", "C", "W", 
"C", "W", "D", "D", "W", "C", "D", "C", "W", "C", "W", "D", "D", 
"W", "C", "D", "C", "W", "C", "W", "D", "D", "W", "C", "D", "C", 
"W", "C", "W", "D", "D", "W", "C", "D", "C", "W", "C", "W", "D", 
"D", "W", "C"), NEE = c(-6.59, -5.96, -10.53, -6.49, -5.52, -10.57, 
-5.67, -9.6, -9.8, -10.42, -13.48, -11.89, -7.49, -6.49, -10.37, 
-5.57, -7.64, -8.11, -6.1, -5.7, -6.57, -7.41, -2.38, -7.92, 
-8.62, -8.39, -7.8, -7.32, -4.63, -6.98, -10.14, -7.65, -10.88, 
-6.41, -4.73, -8.11, -1.55, 1.35, -0.13, 1.79, -2.62, -1.11, 
-3.05, -3.14, -3.94, -4.67, -3.52, -3.3, 0.09, -3.47, -2.21, 
-0.34, -0.75, -2.59, -1.55, -0.55, -1.82, 0.11, -3.12, 0.54, 
-0.87, -0.85, -2.36, -0.44, -0.06, -0.32, 0.61, -0.95, 1.41, 
1.31, 3.36, 1.26, 2.49, 1.85, 2.73, 0.88, 1.35, 2.24, -2.49, 
-2.19, -7.56, -3.74, -5.47, -0.93, -4.83, -7.53, -3.94)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-87L))
```

I want to calculate the relative response of `NEE`= (D-C)/C based on the same TIME, and then build up a new data frame with `TIME` and `NEE`. But now the problem is under different `TIME`, there are different `Plots` (the first date with only 3 plots but others have 9 plots).

How to solve this problem?

My expected results would be like this,

```
TIME                    NEE
02/02/2010       (-6.59+5.96)/(-5.96)
26/02/2010       [average(-6.49,-9.80,-10.42)-average(-5.52,-5.67,-11.89)]/average(-5.52,-5.67,-11.89)
...
```

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: @MartinGal I edited the post with my expected outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<- tapply(it.df$NEE,list(it.df$TIME,it.df$Treat),mean) #here you will get a list

df <- cbind(date = rownames(df), df) 
#change the first index column (or row names) into the first column
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(df) 
#make the row names contain the index column(or row names)

df<- as.data.frame(df)  #change list to dataframe
df$C<- as.numeric(df$C)
df$D<- as.numeric(df$D)
df$W<- as.numeric(df$W)

df$RRD<- (df$D-df$C)/(df$C)*100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# make a copy of your df
test <- df

# remove "plot" as you do not really need it
test$Plot <- NULL

# get "mean" of "NEE" for each "TIME + Treat" condition
test <- aggregate(NEE ~ TIME + Treat, data = test, mean)

# sort data by date
test <- test[order(test$TIME),]

# get all unique days
# not sure how should I interpret the dates here: as.Date(days,"%d/%m/%y") ???
days <- unique(test$TIME)  

# anyway, for each day, you can still get the data needed and do the calculation

test_subset <- list()
C <- list()
D <- list()
W <- list()
RRD <- list()

for(i in 1:length(days)){
  test_subset[[i]] <- test[which(test$TIME == days[[i]]),]
  C[[i]] <- test_subset[[i]][test_subset[[i]]$Treat == "C",]$NEE
  D[[i]] <- test_subset[[i]][test_subset[[i]]$Treat == "D",]$NEE
  W[[i]] <- test_subset[[i]][test_subset[[i]]$Treat == "W",]$NEE
  RRD[[i]] <- (D[[i]]-C[[i]])/C[[i]]*100
}

# combine your days, and target results
results <- cbind(days,C,D,W,RRD)
results <- as.data.frame(results)
results
```